# Max retries exceeded....Failed to establish a new connection: [Error 111] 'Connection refused'

Tags: python, post, connection, localhost

I am trying to upload a description to the localhost via requests.post() method. But the error keeps coming for max retries.
How can I reduce that and, is there any way around to get past this?

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
import requests

URL = "http://35.226.232.234/fruits"
description_files = os.listdir("supplier- 
data/descriptions")
image_names = [img for img in 
os.listdir("supplier-data/images/") if img[-4: ] == 'jpeg']
image_index = 0

for file in description_files:
    description = {}

    with open("supplier-data/descriptions/" + file, 'r') as des_file:
        lines = des_file.readlines()
        description['name'] = lines[0]
        description['weight'] = int(lines[1][:-4])
        description['description'] = lines[2]
        description['image_name'] = image_names[image_index]
        image_index += 1

    response = requests.post(URL, data = description)
    print(response.ok)
    time.sleep(5)`
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of token auth?

Comment: No, I am not using any token auth. At first, I thought I am making too many requests to the server, then I decided to add "time.sleep(5)" to delay the requests, But it still shows the error

Comment: Are you able to ping the server from your local machine?

Comment: The error means that there's nothing listening at that IP/Port combination in my experience